# How to recover files that have been accidentally lost after a git commit

Tags: git

I had initialized a git repo with and staged and committed the changes.

```
$ git inti
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Commit message."
```

Being young and reckless, I accidentally and playfully typed in the command

```
$ git rm * -r
```

and lost all my life's work.

Is there any way I can get my files back for I need them urgently and desperately!

Comment: Given that you *did* commit, just use `git reset` to put things back the way they were.  In particular `git reset --hard` undoes changes to both the index *and* the work-tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

This should undo your changes.

Comment: I doubt the OP wants `HEAD^` as the undesired changes are not yet committed.

Comment: @torek, ah yes you are correct. I will change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**You can also do this**

```
 git cherry-pick #commitNumber
```